# Use One Button To ShrinK & Grow

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, size

On my windows form, I want to add a button that will allow to grow and/or shrink the form.  Can this be done with just one button or will I need to add in 2 separate buttons?  This is the code I am using to grow on the button press.  How can if the button is pressed again go to a smaller size?

```
private void buttonGrowShrink(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Size = new Size(320, 490);
}
```

How can I then use same button to shrink to a smaller size if the button is pressed again?

Comment: It isn't impossible, you could use Control.ModifierKeys for example to check if the user is holding down, say, the Shift key.  It does however make for a pretty horrible UI, the user doesn't stand a chance to discover this by himself.  You'll have to write a manual.  Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for that insight.  I'll just use 2 buttons but have them in the exact same place and hide/unhide based off the button press event so that only the correct button is shown at the correct time.

Comment: Users know how to resize a window.  Just don't help.

Comment: While I agree with @HansPassant in general, there are some cases where it is appropriate for the program to change it's own size. For example check out the `Calculator` program in windows. It is not resizable by the user, but if you change the `View`, the form resizes to accommodate additional (or fewer) controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions are below. In both cases I also changed the text of the button so the user knows what will happen if they push it, but this would be optional.

One way would be to use a Boolean to track the current size of the form:

```
private bool formIsLarge = false;

private void buttonGrowShrink(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (formIsLarge)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(160, 245);
        button1.Text = "Grow Form";
    }
    else
    {
        this.Size = new Size(320, 490);
        button1.Text = "Shrink Form";
    }

    formIsLarge = !formIsLarge;
}
```

Another way would be to just compare the current size of the form with the 'large' and 'small' sizes and change the size accordingly:

```
private void buttonGrowShrink(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var largeSize = new Size(320, 490);
    var smallSize = new Size(160, 245);

    if (this.Size.Width >= largeSize.Width || this.Size.Height >= largeSize.Height)
    {
        this.Size = smallSize;
        button1.Text = "Grow Form";
    }
    else
    {
        this.Size = largeSize;
        button1.Text = "Shrink Form";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to toggle between two sizes. Let's use (400,300) and (600,200) for example. Just add those values together to get a constant size. Then subtract the current size from that constant every time the button is clicked. Like so:

```
private void buttonGrowShrink(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(1000, 500) - this.Size;
}
```